# Clean Archtecture. Understanding of scheme

Tags: java, android, clean-architecture

can you help me to understand the next thing right? So, I read Clean Architecture by R.Martin and there are many schemes.

**Picture 1:**

[image: picture 1]

My implementation:

**Billing.java**

```
public class Billing {

    public Billing(){

        //creating of licenses
        License personalLicense = new PersonalLicense();
        License businessLicense = new BusinessLicense();

        //method using
        personalLicense.calcFee();
        businessLicense.calcFee();
    }
}
```

**License.java**

```
public interface License {
    public void calcFee();
}
```

**PersonalLicense.java**

```
public class PersonalLicense implements License {

    public PersonalLicense(){
        //constructor implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void calcFee(){
        //method implementation here
    }
}
```

**BusinessLicense.java**

```
public class BusinessLicense implements License {

    //private ? users - Unknown type just for example

    @Override
    public BusinessLicense(){
        //constructor implementation here
    }

    public void calcFee(){
        //method implementation here
    }
}
```

**Picture 2:**
[image]

My implementation:

**U1Ops.java**

```
public interface U1Ops{
    public void op1();
}
```

**U2Ops.java**

```
public interface U2Ops{
    public void op2();
}
```

**U3Ops.java**

```
public interface U3Ops{
    public void op3();
}
```

**OPS.java**

```
public class OPS implements U1Ops, U2Ops, U3Ops{
    public OPS(){ ... }

    @Override
    public void op1() { ... }

    @Override
    public void op2() { ... }

    @Override
    public void op3() { ... }
}
```

**User1.java**

```
public class User1 {
    public User1(){
        OPS u1Ops = new U1Ops();
        u1Ops.op1();
    }
}
```

**User2.java**

```
public class User2 {
    public User2(){
        OPS u2Ops = new U2Ops();
        u2Ops.op2();
    }
}
```

**User3.java**

```
public class User3 {
    public User3(){
        OPS u3Ops = new U3Ops();
        u3Ops.op3();
    }
}
```

**Picture 3:**
[image]

My implementation:

**Permissions.java**

```
public class Permissions{

    public Permissions() { ... }

    public classMethod() { ... }
}
```

**User1.java**

```
public class User1 {
    public User1(){
        Permissions p = new Permissions();
        p.classMethod();
    }
}
```

**UNDERLINE IMPLEMENTATION**

**IPermissions.java**

```
public interface IPermissions{
    public void interfaceMethod()();
}
```

**Permissions.java**

```
public class Permissions implements IPermissions{

    public Permissions() { ... }

    @Override
    public interfaceMethod() { ... }
}
```

**User2.java**

```
public class User2 {
    public User2(){
        IPermissions p = new Permissions();
        p.interfaceMethod();
    }
}
```

The common detail of these schemes is:
[image]

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public Main(){
        ITest t = new Test();
        t.someMethod();
    }
}
```

**ITest.java**

```
public interface ITest{
    public void someMethod()();
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test implements ITest{

    public Test() { ... }

    @Override
    public someMethod() { ... }
}
```

Do I understand these schemes right?

Comment: I do not know how to answer your question. Do you want to know if the schemas match your code or what the ideas are behind the schemas? Please elaborate the specific question / problem that you have.

Comment: @Bram yeah, you're right! Do the schemas match my code? Because I think if they do then I understand they right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Picture 1:

`License`, `PersonalLicense`, `BusinessLicense` is ok, `Billing` must be like that:

```java
public class Billing {
    private Lisense license;

    public Billing(License license){
        this.license = license;
    }

    public void pay(){
       // some code
       this.license.calcFee();
       // some code
    }

    public void setLicense(License license){
        this.license = license;
    }
}
```

It's look like [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which lets you define a family of algorithms(`License`), put each of them into a separate class(`PersonalLicense`,`BusinessLicense`), and make their objects interchangeable. Main feature is that `Billing` class only know that it has some License object, which can `calcFee`, without knowing a specific implementation. Later, for supporting new license types, you will create new implementations of `License` and won't modify `Billing`.

### Picture 2:

`User1`, `User2`, `User3`, must be something like that, with corresponding U*Ops:

```java
public class User1 {
    private U1Ops u1Ops;
    public User1(U1Ops u1Ops){
        this.u1Ops = u1Ops;
    }
}

// usage of classes
OPS ops = new OPS();
User1 user1 = new User1(ops);
User2 user2 = new User2(ops);
```

Looks like example of interface segregation principle from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) it states that no client(`User1`, `User2`, `User3`) should be forced to depend on methods it does not use(`User1` only need `op1()`).

### Picture 3:

As in previous examples, association must be implemented with `User` instance field. Those diagrams demonstrates [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (upper - bad practice, underline - good practice). According it, `User` must know only about some abstract `Permissions` interface and not about specific implementation, `Permissions` class know only about `Permissions` interface which it implements. With usage of this principle, `Entities` module create their own abstractions level([API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)) - `Permissions` interface and `Authorizer` using it. Related term to it is [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with commonly used in java frameworks (e.g. [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/)) for low [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) between modules

Comment: I think I get it. You know, I thought that if `Billing` uses `License` from **Picture 1** it means that we use new instance (`PersonalLicense` or `BusinessLicense`) of `License` type inside `Billing` but actually we do the next thing: `Billing b = new Billing(new PersonalLicense());` and `Billing b = new Billing(new BusinessLicense())`.

Comment: In short, we create new instance of each `License` implementation and put them inside `Billing` which only know that it has some `License` object, am I right?